# Angular 7 - adding data to an array instead of replacing it

Tags: javascript, arrays, get, angular7

I'm getting data from wordpress api after button click:

```
<a (click)="initGetComments()">Get comments</a>
```

this is the code:

```
export class AppComponent {

  commentsResults: CommentsItem[] = [];

  getComments(ID:string): Observable<CommentsItem[]> {
    console.log(ID);

    return this.http
      .get(`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/${ID}/replies/?number=1`)
      .map(res =>
        res.comments.map(
          item =>
            new CommentsItem(
              item.post.ID,
              item.ID,
              item.author.name,
              item.author.avatar_URL,
              item.date,
              item.raw_content
            )
        )
      );
  }

  initGetComments(){
    var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('single-post');

    var i=0;
    for( i; i < posts.length; i++ ) {
      this.getComments(posts[i].id).subscribe(data => {
        this.commentsResults = data;
        console.warn("commentsResults =", this.commentsResults);
      })
    }

  }
}

export class CommentsItem {
  constructor(
    public post_ID: number,
    public ID: number,
    public author: string,
    public avatar: string,
    public date: string,
    public content: string
  ) {}
}
```

And result:

[image]

I would like store all of this requests data into a single array instead of replacing it and would be great if each of request induced by a for loop be send when the previous one has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `this.commentsResults.push(data);`

Comment: Thanks for targeting, that create array of arrays instead of array of records but I have created another empty array where im pushing single records.

Comment: Oh I missed that data would be an array. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

`this.commentsResults.merge(data);`.
Instead of this: `this.commentsResults = data;`